# What to write instead of CMS Address?

Tags: content-management-system, server, client, client-server, ip-address

I want to realize a digital signage via Xibo software on some TV screens. I've downloaded xibo-server-170-rc1.tar, xibo-client-1.7.4-win32-x86 and installed Xibo. However, I've inserted nothing in CMS Address and key when Xibo Player Options window has opened although I gave some admin user key during an installation. Then I've tried to add a display IP and Mac Address. However,as it is possible only from the client side, I have started to install Xibo client server on another computer. But I don't know what I must insert as a CMS address and key by a side of client. (I've not done it also by a side of server)

I'm a new in Xibo topic.

Answer (score 0):

The actual server setup which is well documented and adding a screen can be found via links below. Do take some time to review the documentation.

For your question you will need the key created during server setup to be used for the client configuration. Additionally, you will need to go into the CMS and 'approve' the new client before it will start to work.

Server Setup and config http://xibo.org.uk/manual/en/install_cms.html

Connecting a Windows Client http://xibo.org.uk/manual/en/install_windows_client.html

Approving the new display can be found here http://xibo.org.uk/manual/en/displays.html